# Reload parent window after iFrame close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i have an sepa-mandate in a popup window with an delete button inside.
When the user click on the delete button he comes to "page2" with an echo to close the iFrame and reload parent page.
I try different ways to reload the parent page but nothing works. Here is my last idea with localstorage:

```
<a href="mandate.php" class="infoboxs" data-fancybox-type="iframe">show mandate</a>
```

Here is the content of "page2 with the close command and the localstorage parameter

```
<!-- IF PAGE eq 2 -->
echo "<script>localStorage.setItem('delete', 1); parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();</script>";
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

Now the parent window is looking for localstorage is set to 1. If its equals 1 it will be set to 0 and the page should be reload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (localStorage.getItem('delete') == 1)
{
    localStorage.setItem('delete', 0);
    location.reload();
}
```

Can any one see whats wrong?
Greetings and nice weekend!

EDIT:
Before i forgot it, feel free to downvote me! :)

Comment: why do you need a popup window? every mobile user would dislike it...

Comment: ok thats a big point, thank you for it. The div around the href has an hidden-phone class. My target group for this function uses desktops computers and no smartphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript runs once. You want to check regularily (every second in my code ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function(){
     if (localStorage.getItem('delete') == 1){
        localStorage.setItem('delete', 0);
        location.reload();
     }
   },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much it works so far. But now i got an dialog to "send the datas again" on the refresh process. Any idea?

Comment: @tobiass that happens if youre reloading a posted page ( is there a form on it ? ). you should rethink your overall structure...

Comment: Yes it was my mistake with the reload dialog, i postet on this page 1 minute before. Your answer works great! Thanks you so much!!! :)